# list of app connected with my onedrive

Tags: web-applications, onedrive

Where can I view list of web applications connected to my OneDrive?
Where can I disable access of application to my OneDrive?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

You can see a list of apps here: https://account.live.com/consent/Manage

Comment: I have a Business account used with One Drive main app. Does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using business account as well, to see connected web applications to your account :

1. login to your account, e.g. via https://onedrive.live.com ;
2. click on your icon in the upper-right corner, and choose "my account" ;
3. then choose "app permissions"

from there you can see the list of connected apps, and revoke if so needed.